# How i get my line of code instead of background process while in break status swift

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

Debugging is making me crazy, because my XCode Debugging is referring background process instead of my exact line of code[image: It's shows while i get into break status]

I don't know what happen to my xcode, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an exception breakpoint.
That will stop debugging on the exact line of code which is causing problem.

1) Click on the **Show the breakpoint Navigator**

2) Click on the plus button at the bottom left corner

3) Select **Exception Breakpoint**

[image]

4) One popup will appear

5) Tap outside that dialog box

[image]

6) You can select Exception option from the dropdown if needed.

[image]

7) Make sure breakpoint is enabled when you run your application

[image]

8) Run your application

Comment: Thank you for the response but i can create break point. Unfortunately when the system get through the break point, it doesn't show where the line break.

Answer (score 0):

It's done by clear caching

type on terminal

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```